# Is it possible to set color to email subject?

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail, html-email

Is it possible to set color to email subject? I tried this below which did not work.

```
//subject = "<FONT COLOR=\"#ff0000\">" + subject + "</FONT>";
subject = "&lt;FONT COLOR=&quot;#ff0000&quot;&gt;Test Subject&lt;/FONT&gt;";
String yourEncodedString = MimeUtility.encodeText(subject, "UTF-8", "B");
message.setHeader("Subject", yourEncodedString);
message.setSubject(yourEncodedString,  "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Have you ever received email with text formatting in the subject? If it were possible, don't you think someone would have done so by now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloring is not a email or SMTP feature. It is ability of client to show HTML documents. Clients that support HTML format parse email body only and show subject as-is. Therefore subject remains as it was created.

So, the bottom line: no you cannot send email with colored subject. I am sorry...

Comment: Thanks, I know its not possible (that's why my question started as Is it possible....) but was checking if someone had any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

This shows [Emogi characters](https://emojipedia.org/unicode-5.2/) (Unicode characters) that happen to be colored in an email subject line.  This is more of a note to myself but it may apply here.

This subject line (from NewEgg) shows text and colors:

[image]

The subject line looks like this:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?4p2X4p2X4p2XIDMgREFZUyBPTkxZIOKdl+Kdl+KdlyAkNTAgTmludGVuZG8gZVNob3AgR2lmdCBDYXJk?=
```

I believe the technique is [Encoded-word Syntax](https://dmorgan.info/posts/encoded-word-syntax/).  In that link Derek Morgan describes the technique relating to RFC2822, RFC2047, RFC2045, and provides example Python code to encode and decode the text.

The format of the above subject content is:

```
=?<charset>?<encoding>?<encoded-text>?=
```

He also mentions this [Github link](https://github.com/buriy/python-readability/issues/42#issuecomment-26580084) that discusses the characters sets.

I went to base64decode.net, pasted in the above, selected Utf-8, and this popped out:

❗❗❗ 3 DAYS ONLY ❗❗❗ $50 Nintendo eShop Gift Card

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is create an Outlook view that colors the messages (subject, sender, etc.) in the Explorer (where Outlook shows the list of messages) based on a value of some property.

That is how Outlook shows overdue messages in red.

Answer (score 0):

I have received many spam mails in gmail where there is images(?) and different fonts used in subject line. So colour may not be possible but it seems formatting is possible

[image]